# PhoneGap development environment for iPhone

Tags: cordova

Must I be on a Mac to develop PhoneGap applications targeted for iOS? I'm a bit confused by the PhoneGap documentation. It seems like I need to install SDKs -- and those SDKs are platform dependent.

Answer (score 2):

In general you need a mac to develop apps for iOs.

**But if** you use https://build.phonegap.com/
the build environment is in the cloud und you only need to upload the asset-files and download a packaged app.

You'll still need an apple-developer account for certificates, etc.

Comment: I guess you should update to say you *don't* need a Mac *if* you use Adobe's Build (which is epic btw). Maybe also worth mentioning the Ripple emulator.

Comment: Can this be combined with TestFlight to deploy to a test device without a Mac or XCode? I suppose you still need a developer account for the signing certificate and device provisioning.